# Relatively position menu-item in a dropdown/collapsible menu?

Tags: html, css

First, [here's the dropdown/collapsible menu](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/fxSYT/) I've constructed.

As for what the "menu" and "menu-item" are in [the preview](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/fxSYT/embedded/result/) shown in the fiddle -- *Channels*, *Search*, and *About Us* are menus, while the ones that drop-down/slide-out when you click on the menus are menu-items.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image: screenshot]

I am using `position: absolute;` on the menu-items (`.collapse`), and `position: relative;` on the menus.

**The Relevant code** ([more in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/fxSYT/)):

```
/* Menu: <li class="float-left top-menu">... */
.top-menu {
    position: relative;
}

/* Menu-Item: <div id="channels-menu-item-container" class="collapse">... */
.collapse {
    position: absolute;
    width: 570px;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality using `position: relative;` on the "menu-item" (`.collapse`) as well?

---

**NOTE:** Before you submit an answer with a fiddle, please do make sure that the menus in both fiddles (yours and mine) are functioning the same *by clicking on each menu and comparing* (so as to confirm that no menu-items are misplaced due to change in positioning).

You may add extra bits of HTML and CSS, of course.

---

And yes, I tried for hours in vain, and wanted to see if it's at all possible.

Comment: If I may ask - what's wrong with `absolute`? Position `absolute` in `relative` works great (for example, `right: 0;` worked very nicely for you in the right-aligned menu) - what isn't working for you? Also, I see the "Editions" box below the other boxes, and not on the right (on Firefox 17)

Comment: @Kobi Yes, exactly. What you see is because I've a specified width on the menu-items (`.collapse`), but I don't want it. If I remove width, the menu-item is no longer horizontal i.e. collapses vertically. But if I can get the menu to work with `relative` I can use `inline-block` instead of `float` for the columns in the menu-item. Get the idea?

Comment: I think so. Well, so is the real question how to get auto width?

Comment: @Kobi Inherently yes. That's right. But I thought the only alternative was to use `position: relative;` and using `inline-block` for columns inside menu-items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

- Remove the width from `.collapse`.
- Remove float from the columns, change to `inline-block`.
- Change `white-space` to `nowrap`.

Html:

```
<div class="in collapse" id="channels-menu-item-container" style="height: auto;">
    <div id="channels-menu-item-wrapper">
        <ul class="channel-column" id="nav-channels">
           <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="channel-column" id="nav-topics">
           <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="channel-column" id="nav-editions">
           <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
        <div class="aahans"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.collapse {
    position: absolute;
    min-width:200px; /*for the seach box*/
    /* ... */
}

#channels-menu-item-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #259;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.channel-column {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

You may also want to reset the `white-space` value in each `.channel-column`.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/fxSYT/1/embedded/result/

Comment: I quickly replicated this on my dev site, and it seems to work just fine, hence marking it as the answer. Unable to take a good look as it's already past 2AM here. **EDIT:** You suggested changing `white-space` to `no-break`, but the CSS in your answer uses `nowrap`. Was that a mistake? Also, what did you mean by, "You may also want to reset the `white-space` value in each `.channel-column`". Did you mean, it's a good idea to use `white-space: normal;` on `.channel-column`? (**PS:** Thanks a lot!)

Comment: @its_me - Yes, that is what I meant, just in case (you may have blocks of text in the columns, for example). Happy to help! (also, please remember to [state the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/7586) clearly. Good night!

Comment: Edited. I think I made up `no-break`. Thanks `:)`

Comment: Hello again. Testing the menu's appearance across different browsers (as its design is complete), I noticed that the menu is actually chipped off in Firefox, like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/D0LD6.png -- Do you see it too? Any idea as to why this could be happening? (sorry I didn't check it earlier.)

Comment: **(...continued)** In your answer you asked me to use `white-space: normal;` on `.channel-column` to reset the property. I just realized that it's the issue I mentioned above. **#2** And the other thing is, the "Search" menu is broken in Chrome (try clicking on it multiple times -- at least thrice, to see for yourself). Any ideas? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @its_me - Hi! Hmm... I can't reproduce the problem you're having with Chrome. I clicked a lot. Consider asking a new question, I'm sure someone will figure it out `:)`

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Maybe it's specific to Chrome/Chromium on Linux distributions.